# Xlookup and search in MS Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, xlookup

I've following sample data:

| Company | Tier | Domain |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Abc | Elite | abc.com, abc.com.uk, abc.co.in |
| Xyz | Professional | xyz.hk, xyz.com |
| Def | Elite | def.sa, def.com |
| Lmn | Elite | lmn.com, lmn.ca |
| fusion | Professional | fusiongbs.com, fusion.com |

I want to fetch the some information of the same ( the main data is on SharePoint - so I can't be altered)

| Fetched data |
| --- |
| abc.com.uk |
| xyz.com |
| def.sa |
| lmn.com |
| fusion.com |

To get the required information:

I wrote the following formula:

```
=IF(SEARCH(F3,VLOOKUP("*"&D3&"*",$D$3:$D$7,1,0),1),XLOOKUP(F3,$D$3:$D$7,$C$3:$C$7," ",0,1))
```

[image]

I tried with various variations of vlookup(), xlookup(), match(), xmatch() but not getting the required information:

Thanks in Advance:

Comment: Try: `=XLOOKUP("*"&E2&"*",$C$2:$C$6,$B$2:$B$6,,2)`

Answer (score 1):

Using `XLOOKUP()` and `Wildcard Character Match Mode`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `F2`

```
=XLOOKUP("*"&E2&"*",$C$2:$C$6,$B$2:$B$6,,2)
```

---

As mentioned by **[JvdV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9758194/jvdv)** Sir, to prevent any `FALSE POSITIVES` and return all values as single go, you could do the below

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `F2`

```
=XLOOKUP("* "&E2:E6&"*"," "&C2:C6&",",B2:B6,"",2)
```

---

Comment: A little more secure would be: `=XLOOKUP("* "&E2:E6&",*"," "&C2:C6&",",B2:B6,"",2)`, just to prevent false positives *and* do all values in a single go.

Comment: @JvdV Sir while using that way it doesnt gets the `def.sa,` shows blank

Comment: That has to be a typo! I cannot imagine that is actual data.

Comment: Sir removed the comma from the lookup value works great then `=XLOOKUP("* "&E2:E6&"*"," "&C2:C6&",",B2:B6,"",2)`